# Easiest way to redeploy an SPFX extension

Tags: deployment, spfx, gulp

I've successfully deployed my first SharePoint Framework extension to my SharePoint Online app catalog + site collection. My question is about deployment efficiency. Currently to deploy, I have to do a

```
gulp bundle
gulp package-solution
```

...then upload the sppkg to the appcatalog along with the assets (js,scss) to a pre-configured CDN library. Then I have to install the actual app on the site collection.

What is the quickest way to deploy a new change if I modify the typescript file and the .scss file? Can I avoid fully retracting the app and re-adding it? That takes the longest because it makes you delete the previous version from the Recycle Bin.

Comment: I have never retracted the app before update.  If you have time you could setup some automation too, one example: http://www.delucagiuliano.com/continuous-integration-and-deployment-for-your-sharepoint-framework-solutions/#.WgFyQWhSwuU

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've been doing:

- Increment the version number in the package-solution.json file
- Upload the new .sppkg and CDN files
- Go to "Add an App" and click "find out why" link on your app and then get the latest version of the file

Answer (score 1):

It should not be necessary to retract the installed version first. Just upload a new .sppkg file to the app catalog and update your CDN.

Comment: You would think, but changes to my Application Customizer are not reflected until I fully retract, remove from 2 recycle bins, then re-install.